# strong element has spaces fix

Tags: html, css

I have this following html codes.

```
<div class="box extend">
    <h1>CLOUD SERVICES FOR SMALL BUSINESS</h1>
    <figure><img src="myimg.png" /></figure>
    <p>
        <strong>Hosted Exchange Server</strong>
        <strong>Cloud Server Solutions</strong>
        <strong>Backup Servicesd Server Solution</strong>
    </p>
</div>
```

and the css of the above html (updated css)

```
.box p strong{
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: red;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background: blue;
}
```

now the problem is the strong element has spaces between each other as supposedly it should not (base on my css set up), please refer to the image below

[image]

Is there anyway I could get raid or remove that space gap between each others element? Any recommendations, suggestions and ideas, I would love to hear! thank you in advance.

Comment: There must be more to your css to force strong tags to act as block elements, can you share more?

Comment: there must be more css on the strong tag itself since it is displaying block right now

Comment: This looks like you might want to use `<ul>` instead.

Comment: There's obviously more CSS involved that you've provided, seeing as your strong elements are behaving as block level elements and have checkmarks next to them that your current CSS doesn't provide for.

Comment: my bad guys, please see my updated post (the css part) the css set up of p is actually for strong element (.box p strong)

Comment: Inspect the strong with firebug or the likes and see the css on it. Strangely enough with line-height set to the same size as the font, it still has a line http://jsfiddle.net/5qqLR/

Answer (score 1):

It seems making them display block kills the thin line

http://jsfiddle.net/5qqLR/2/

```
.box p strong{
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: red;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background: blue;
    display: block;
}
```

After further research setting the parent line-height to 1 will solve this issue

http://jsfiddle.net/5qqLR/3/

```
.box p {
    line-height: 1;
}
```

Take a look at here http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?824112-space-below-inline-elements-inside-a-block-element

Answer (score 1):

Add to strong HTML tag:
`white-space: break-spaces;`